# Collection Select Helper in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a quick question in regards to the collection_select helper in Rails 3.

I would like to create a drop down field whereby a user can select a country from a list.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:country,:id,SyncedCountry.order('name ASC'),:name,:name,{},{:class => "input-xlarge"}) %>
```

When I submit on the page I see something like this in the params for country:

```
"country"=>{"id"=>"Antilles"}
```

What I really want is the id of the country selected in the drop-down and not in a hash format. So the result would be more like:

"country"=> 1 (the id of a country selected)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<%= collection_select(:country,:id,SyncedCountry.order('name ASC'),:name,:name,{},{:class => "input-xlarge"}) %>
```

with

```
<%= collection_select(:model_object,:country,SyncedCountry.order('name ASC'),:name,:name,{},{:class => "input-xlarge"}) %>
```

where `model_object` is the object passed to form. If its a form for `user` and your form looks like `form_for(@user)` then replace `:model_object` with `:user`.

So, params would look like `"user"=>{"country"=>"Antilles"}`, assuming that you are setting country for a user.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select):

> `collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) public`
>   ...
>
> The `:value_method` and `:text_method`parameters are methods to be called
>   on each member of collection. The return values are used as the value
>   attribute and contents of each `<option>` tag, respectively. They can
>   also be any object that responds to call, such as a proc, that will be
>   called for each member of the collection to retrieve the value/text.

So try:

```
<%= collection_select(:country,:id,SyncedCountry.order('name ASC'),:id,:name,{},{:class => "input-xlarge"}) %>
```

The example in the documentation looks like this:

> Sample usage (selecting the associated `Author` for an instance of `Post`,
>   `@post`):
>
> ```
> collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id,
>   :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
> ```
>
> If `@post.author_id` is already `1`, this would return:
>
> ```
> <select name="post[author_id]">
>   <option value="">Please select</option>
>   <option value="1" selected="selected">D. Heinemeier Hansson</option>
>   <option value="2">D. Thomas</option>
>   <option value="3">M. Clark</option>
> </select>
> ```

(this will return "author_id"=>"1")

Now, I'm not familiar with your model, but if you are selecting the country of your user, than I think this should work:

```
    <%= collection_select(:user, :country_id,SyncedCountry.order('name ASC'),:id,:name,{},{:class => "input-xlarge"}) %>
```

Comment: That pretty much works but the param looks like this: `country"=>{"id"=>"1"}` Is there anyway to not have the param passed as a hash, so I just get the ID instead, i.e. "country" => 1.